# How to tuning parameter in multi rake python?

Tags: python, rake, text-extraction

I want to get the right summary output, therefore I try to make some changes to the parameters, but the output remains as expected. Is there a way to tuning parameters in the Rake object? how to get optimal parameters multi rake pyhton

This is the code

```
rake = Rake(
    min_chars=3,
    max_words=3,
    min_freq=1,
    language_code='id',  # 'en'
    stopwords=stopwordsid2,  # {'and', 'of'}
    lang_detect_threshold=10,
    max_words_unknown_lang=2,
    generated_stopwords_percentile=10,
    generated_stopwords_max_len=3,
    generated_stopwords_min_freq=1, )
```

I just want to know how to tuning the optimal parameter in Rake